Adding Contents of ChatPromptTemplate from multiple parts - Langchain V0.2
I have a prompt which consists of some fixed text parts and other varient text parts. I am using langchain v 0.2. I would like to build up ChatPromptTemplate from multiple parts, and then use it in a chain to get an answer from the llm.
I have the following 3 parts:

system_message_prompt: System, fixed text.
notes_message_prompt: Varient, may be considered system or human, in this question I will consider it human.
user_message_prompt: Human, varient text.

But I have a problem with selecting/using the correct parts/libraries.
from langchain_huggingface import HuggingFaceEndpoint

from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain_core.prompts import PromptTemplate, ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder
from langchain_core.messages import HumanMessage, SystemMessage
from langchain_core.prompts.chat import HumanMessagePromptTemplate, SystemMessagePromptTemplate

....

system_template = "ABC"
system_message_prompt = SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(system_template)

notes_template = "EFG"
notes_message_prompt = HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(notes_template)

user_template = "YXZ {this}"
user_message_prompt = HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(user_template)

chat_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
    system_message_prompt,
    notes_message_prompt,
    user_message_prompt
])

filled_chat_prompt = chat_prompt.format(this = 'some data')

....

llm_chain = filled_chat_prompt | myllmFromHuggingFace

The error I get is:
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-7697f8d4a2c1> in <cell line: 10>()
      8 )
      9 
---> 10 llm_chain = filled_chat_prompt | myllmFromHuggingFace

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain_core/runnables/base.py in coerce_to_runnable(thing)
   5513         return cast(Runnable[Input, Output], RunnableParallel(thing))
   5514     else:
-> 5515         raise TypeError(
   5516             f"Expected a Runnable, callable or dict."
   5517             f"Instead got an unsupported type: {type(thing)}"

TypeError: Expected a Runnable, callable or dict.Instead got an unsupported type: <class 'str'>

I am using langchain 0.2.

Is this the full error message?

Please see updated error message.
